# Flutter. How to add Padding for SliverGrid

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, flutter-gridview

I use CustomScrollView with SliverGrid. I add space between grid items using this:
mainAxisSpacing: 8, crossAxisSpacing: 8.
But is it possible to add space (margin/padding) before the first and after the last column.
I tried to wrap my SliverGrid in Padding, but I get the error:

> A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a
> child of type RenderPadding.
>
> RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they
> coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a
> RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver
> does not understand

Please, help me how to add start and end margin of my GridView.

Comment: use `mainAxisSpacing: 10.0`,
            `crossAxisSpacing: 10.0`,

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the [SliverPadding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverPadding-class.html) class:

```
SliverPadding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
        sliver: SliverGrid.count(
          ...
        ),
      ),
```